# How to pass arguments between pages in XAML without causing loading issues

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, xaml

Apologies in advance I have less than a month of XAML and WPF experience and have been googling as much as possible but here we go.

I have a window that has a single frame inside of it, I have been using pages that swap out what is inside the frame. I have been doing this like this for example:

```
private void NextPageButtonPressed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2())
}
```

This works just fine for navigation when data is not being passed but when I try to go from page2 to page3 and try to pass data from various checkboxes and combo boxes as so:

```
private void GoToNextPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          
    object[] isKaliAndDistroSelected = new object[] {GetIsKali(), GetSelectedDistro()};
    Page3 pg3 = new Page3();
    this.NavigationService.LoadCompleted += pg3.NavigationService_LoadCompleted;
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(pg3, isKaliAndDistroSelected);            
}
```

with the following code on Page3:

```
private string distro="";
private bool isKali = false;

public Page3()
{
    InitializeComponet();
    RunOnDoneLoadingPage(distro,isKali);
}

public void NavigationService_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var test = (object[]) e.ExtraData;
    isKali = (bool) test[0];
    distro = (string) test[1];
    NavigationService.LoadCompleted -= NavigationService_LoadCompleted;
}
```

it ends up not updating the values isKali or distro unless I place the `RunOnDoneLoadingPage(distro,isKali);` at the end of the `NavigationService_LoadCompleted`function on Page3. The reason I do not want this is because I want the page to load and THEN run the `RunOnDoneLoadingPage()` because the function manipulates a loading/progress bar. When I place it in the `NavigationService_LoadCompleted` page2 always freezes for a few before displaying Page3 with a loading/progress at 100% making the loading page essentially useless.

So my question is how can I pass data between 2 pages and have the next page display itself but not start a method until the data from the previous page has been passed

Thank you in advance, like I said I'm fairly new to working with XAML so if I can provide more please let me know

Comment: MVVM can help you. Just update your view model to update your views (pages), instead of manually modify the control properties. And share same view model object between all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVVM can help you.
this is a simple view model:

```
public class MyVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string propAOfPage1;
    public string PropAOfPage1
    {
        get => propAOfPage1;
        set
        {
            if (value != this.propAOfPage1)  
            {  
                propAOfPage1= value;  
                NotifyPropertyChanged();  
            }
        }
    }

    private string propBOfPage1;
    public string PropBOfPage1
    {
        get => propBOfPage1;
        set
        {
            if (value != this.propBOfPage1)  
            {  
                propBOfPage1= value;  
                NotifyPropertyChanged();  
            }
        }
    }

    private string propCOfPage2;
    public string PropCOfPage2
    {
        get => propCOfPage2;
        set
        {
            if (value != this.propCOfPage2)  
            {  
                propCOfPage2= value;  
                NotifyPropertyChanged();  
            }
        }
    }

    private string propDOfPage2;
    public string PropDOfPage2
    {
        get => propDOfPage2;
        set
        {
            if (value != this.propDOfPage2)  
            {  
                propDOfPage2= value;  
                NotifyPropertyChanged();  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a simple view:

```
<!-- Page1 -->
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Prop A:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding PropAOfPage1}" Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Prop B:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding PropBOfPage1}" Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

```
<!-- Page2 -->
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Prop C:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding PropCOfPage2}" Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Prop D:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding PropDOfPage2}" Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

just set `Frame.DataContext` as a `MyVM` object, them this `MyVM` object will share between your pages. you can navigate freely and need not consider to get or set the control property in each page.

Extended reading: https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+frame+page+mvvm

Comment: Thank you I had no idea what MVVM even was. After A LOT of learning, I finally got it working using MVVMCross!